# ASP.NET Core MVC 3.1 UseExceptionHandler не перехватывает исключения в синхронных действиях контроллеров

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Пытаюсь глобально обрабатывать исключения с помощью UseExceptionHandler и перенаправлять на пользовательскую страницу со сведениями об ошибке. Это работает ожидаемым образом при вызове асинхронных методов контроллера. При вызове синхронных методов исключение вызывает остановку приложения.
Пробовал на типовом шаблоне приложения asp.net core mvc. Для теста создаю метод Test, в первом варианте открывается страница с ошибкой. Во втором случае исключение останавливает приложение.

```
1.public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
        {
            throw new Exception("My exception");
            return View();
        }
2.public IActionResult> Test()
        {
            throw new Exception("My exception");
            return View();
        }
```

Прошу подсказать причину данного поведения.

Answer (score 0):

Не учел, при запуске приложения в отладочном режиме(f5) исключения не обрабатываются с помощью UseExceptionHandler. Вопрос снимается.